# I have to add input box on particular loop but while i am trying to add new input box , it will add in all the loop in angular formarray

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

Visit:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-dywppj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

i was trying to this resolve this issue from more than three days but didn't any solution , please help what i need to do :- I need to get input box on the particular row where i clicked on add button but when i click on add button it will add input box in each and every index at array.for more details you can check my stackblitz link.

[image]

```
        **********angular formarray ***********
        
        HTML Code :-
       
            <form *ngIf="usersForm" [formGroup]="usersForm" (ngSubmit)="createUsers()">
              <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <ng-container *ngFor='let in of counter(this.totalWords) ;let i = index'>  // this is loop for getting automatically some number of input box as per requirment
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name"/>
            
                  <tbody formArrayName="users">
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of usersForm.controls.users.controls; let $index=index" [formGroupName]="$index">
                      <td style="min-width: 120px">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="address"/>
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['address'].touched
                                         && usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['address'].hasError('required')">
                          Please enter address!
                        </div>
                      </td>
            
                      <td style="min-width: 120px">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="address"/>
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['phone'].touched
                                         && usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['phone'].hasError('required')">
                          Please enter phone number!
                        </div>
                      </td>
            
                      <td style="width: 100px">
                        <button (click)="addUserRow(i)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1" type="button">add</button>
                        <button (click)="removeUserRow($index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">delete</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </ng-container>
            
              </table>
            
              <button (click)="submit()"> submit</button>
            </form>
        
        
        
        ********Typescript Code ************
        
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { Customer } from './customer.interface';
        import {FormControl,FormGroup,FormArray,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html'
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          usersForm: FormGroup;
          errorMessage: string;
          constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        
          }
          ngOnInit() {
            this.usersForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              name:'',
              users: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.formBuilder.group({
                  address: [null, [Validators.required]],
                  phone: [null, [Validators.required]]
                })
              ])
            });
          }
        
          initUserRow(): FormGroup {
            return this.formBuilder.group({
              address: [null, [Validators.required]],
              phone: [null, [Validators.required]],
            });
          }
        
// Here i am adding input box
          addUserRow(i): void {
        
            const usersArray =
              <FormArray>this.usersForm.controls['users'];
            usersArray.push( this.initUserRow());
          }
       
          submit(){
            console.log(this.usersForm.value)
          }
        
          
          counter(i: number) {
            return new Array(2);
          }
        }
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bvkb.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It because of the two `*ngFor` in the table you are using.

1st one :

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let in of counter(this.totalWords) ;let i = index'>
```

I am not sure why you have added this. But this is working as expected. It runs two time and create two instance of everything that comes within because you have used:

```
counter(i: number) {
            return new Array(2);
          }
```

Now, You have used another loop for forms generating,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of usersForm.controls.users.controls; let $index=index" [formGroupName]="$index">
```

that basically have two instance itself because of parent ***ngFor**. And when you are pushing anything to its instance, it basically push in both the `DOM` that has been created by parent `*ngFor`

You can create one instance that will fix your issue. I am not sure why it is like that on purpose or just a mistake.

```
counter(i: number) {
            return new Array(1); // change to 1
          }
```

or I will suggest don't use parent `*ngFor` loop.

But This is the issue that repeat the forms.

You can still use two loops to generate forms and perform add and delete control functionality.

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-fgk1uq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Form validation code is commented, you can implement rest of functionality based on that approach.

Basically use a parent array that can reference a child array to push and pop on its own instance.

Comment: I will tell you whole scenerio: 

take an exampe :- 

var string_data = "I am software _  enginner _"   // if there is two underscore than i need to show 2 input box 

and i can add child input box for each and every parent box

hope you got my point...
that's why i need to use this loop
<ng-container *ngFor='let in of counter(this.totalWords) ;let i = index'>

Comment: Got you, I have updated the answer and added stackbiltz. You can use a parent array to achieve this. It a bit complex but result can be achieved. I feel template based from would be more easy and simple here. Any way All the best. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-fgk1uq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I need to get all the fromarray values inside array of object , but gettng always null  or single string value, and while increase new input box  gettting error " Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 1'"

can you please check :- what's i am doing wrong ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-ogpkmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: That error because it doesn't find control in the group. I think you need to revisit and spend some more time for this complicated form structure. Here you can read about it, this is similar to what you want to do. This will help you. 
https://ramya-bala221190.medium.com/a-simple-example-how-to-implement-nested-formgroups-and-formarrays-in-angular-6f78d7d4b6a3